# Serial communications between PySerial and VEX EDR Cortex

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial, uart, robotc

I have been struggling with this for the last 24 hours, I am trying to get PySerial to talk to a VEX Cortex over bluetooth using UART / HC-05.  I guess this would be very similar to communicating with a Arduino.

The devices are connected together and data is flowing but its junk

In RobotC:(as you can see no encoding is apparent, i believe its just going over as bytes)

```
#include "BNSlib_HC05.h"

task main()
{

    setBaudRate(UART1, baudRate19200);
    bnsATGetBaudrate(UART1)

    char stringBuffer[100];;
    while(1==1)
    {
        bnsSerialRead(UART1, stringBuffer, 100, 100);
        writeDebugStreamLine(stringBuffer);
        delay(500);
        bnsSerialSend(UART1, (char*)&"simon");
    }
}
```

In python PySerial

```
import serial
import time
import struct

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM8', baudrate=19200)
print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
message = "Simon"

while True:
    ser.write(message.encode()) # I guess this is encoding via utf8?
    #for b in bytearray("simon was here","UTF-8"):
        #ser.write(b)

    print("sent")
    time.sleep (100.0 / 1000.0);
    result = ser.read(25) # tried readline, just hangs
    print(">> " + result.decode('cp1252')) # tried utf8, ascii

ser.close()
print("close")
```

In robotC I get back f˜fžþžøž
In Python I am getting back ýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýýý

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the HC-05 module was not configured correctly :(